# Long TTFB on simple GET query in Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

We notice long TTFB on multiple simple GET queries:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("sebTestA/{id}")]
public string SebTestA(int id)
{
    return "test string";
}
```

As you can see, no access to DB or files so should be very fast and I am in localhost (no network issues).

When I execute a single query, is fast (~ 30ms)
When I launch simultaneously 10 queries, it become higher and can reach 1s which makes my app hang up.

Here's the capture of the query in Chrome dev tools:

[image: query in Chrome dev tools]

I have no idea where this latency came from and I have added some log in global.asax.cs in Application_BeginRequest and Application_EndRequest:

here're log records for 10 queries:

[image: for 10 queries]

As you can see, query No.6 took 453ms and in my log is only 8ms. The question is where come from this ~400ms?

Comment: What is a "TTFB"?

Comment: Time To First Byte (TTFB) is a measurement used as an indication of the responsiveness of a webserver or other network resource. TTFB measures the duration from the user or client making an HTTP request to the first byte of the page being received by the client's browser.

Answer (score 2):

This delay is due to the lock/unlock on session managed by ASP.NET.
As is a Web Api, you shouldn't use session. Look at that page for your authentication:
https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api

Otherwise, without changing lot of code, you can update your Global.asax.cs file with:

```
void MvcApplication_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
}
```

Look at this complete post for the detailled answer:
https://forums.iis.net/t/1234877.aspx?Performance+issue+on+IIS+on+multiples+GET+queries